# Python argparse doesn't show up help message correctly

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have to parse arguments where 4 of them have to be tied with each other, and last 2 have to be exclusive

group 1 `sub_exclusive_1` has 4 arguments where all of them must be defined if any of them have been defined.

group 2 `sub_exclusive_2` has 2 arguments where only 1 of them can be defined but only if none from group 1 have been defined.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Main Description', epilog='Main Epilog')
group_exclusive = parser.add_argument_group('Exclusive')
root_exclusive = group_exclusive.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

sub_exclusive_1 = root_exclusive.add_argument_group()
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("--firstList", action='store', help = "Help for firstList")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("--secondList", action='store', help = "Help for secondList")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("--thirdList", action='store', help = "Help for thirdList")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("--fourthList", action='store', help = "Help for fourthList")

sub_exclusive_2 = root_exclusive.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("--last", action='store_true', help = "Help for Last")
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("--first", action='store_true', help = "Help for First")
```

the problems are:

1. Cannot tie group 1 arguments with each other.
2. When setting `sub_exclusive_1` as `add_argument_group` instead of
   `add_mutually_exclusive_group`, `firstList ... fourthList` are not shown in the
   help section when running program with `-h` option.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print_help` that I get from your code (which you should have shown) is

```
In [420]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--firstList FIRSTLIST] [--secondList SECONDLIST]
                [--thirdList THIRDLIST] [--fourthList FOURTHLIST]
                [[--last | --first]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

Exclusive:
  --last      Help for Last
  --first     Help for First
```

All the arguments appear in the `usage`, but only `exclusive_group` appears in the help.  And the brackets on this group in the usage are messed up.

`argparse` does not provide a mechanism to do what you want.  There are some proposed patches that might get you there, but nothing now.

A 'argument group' is just a help lines display mechanism.  It does not affect the usage formatting, and does not affect parsing.  In addition, argument groups cannot be nested - the arguments are accepted, but do not appear in the help.

A mutually exclusive group can be nested in an argument group (for help line display purposes).  But the effect is to just show its arguments in that group.

If you want 'first','second', etc to occur together, either make them values of a `nargs=4` argument, or test them after parsing.  Something like:

```
 group = [args.first, args.second, args.third, args.fourth]
 if any([x is None for x in group]):
     parser.error('all of the inclusive group is required')
```

I could point you to the bug issue that deals with 'nested inclusive groups', but that's not going to help right now.

Comment: ok seems legit, but here accures another question, can i deactivate help message for the `group1` to add it in `ArgumentParser` as `epilog` ? this would be a great workaround

Comment: `argparse.SUPPRESS` is often used to subpress various types of help output.  I don't know if it will work in this situation or not.  You may have to use it in each argument.

Comment: ahh that's it! It does what i want :) Now i can add that part into the epilog of the main description

Answer (score 0):

Group 1 should not be four separate arguments, but a single option with 4 arguments:

```
add_argument("--arg", nargs=4)
```

Then `command --arg1 2 --arg2 3 --arg3 5 --arg4 7` would become `command --arg 2 3 5 7`; you would need to adjust your code accordingly. One option is to adjust the values stored in the namespace after parsing:

```
args = p.parse_args()
# Unpack the 4-tuple into the destinations used by your original parser
args.arg1, args.arg2, args.arg3, args.arg4 = args.arg
```

Another is to define a custom action for `--arg` which immediately assigns the 4 values to the correct destinations in the namespace.

Then you can define an exclusive group containing `--arg`, `--first`, and `--last`.

Comment: but each argument in group 1 has an individual name... it would be wrong to define same argument 4 times

Comment: yes that would be great if all of my arg's had the same name `arg` but actually they are not... see my edits

Comment: Why are the four individual names important *to the user*? Essentially, your requirement is just that they supply a full group of four (presumably related) values. Forcing them to type three additional option strings just to do so just makes using your command more complicated.